# ASP.Net MVC Directory Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I am using and I am using Visual Studio Community 2019. I created the "Hello World" website using the wizard. The file structure looks like the image below. I have found information on this but image of the directory structure never seems to have the wwwroot directory.

What would be the best practice for where to put the Content folder which would then contain an image folder and possibly a documents folder?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wwwroot` is the default folder for serving static files. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1). So yes, it is the correct place to put images and documents.

As per the docs you can create more locations to serve static files from. e.g this serves files from the `StaticFiles` directory.

```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    });
```

This is of course assuming they will be served statically. If you needed to authenticate or anything when looking at docs/files you would need to implement a different solution.